# Finding exhaustive list of isotopes known to have the induced-fission property

Tags: nuclear-physics, elements, isotopes

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, since I am looking for help finding information.

I am making course material in low level nuclear physics. For this, I've created my own visual Segre Chart (nuclear isotope chart) in Manim/Python. I am going to talk about fission and induced-fission property. I would like to be able to highlight all of the isotopes that have the induced-fission property. This should look really cool, as we expect only isotopes over Iron/Nickel should have this property.

i.e. a list of fissionable not just fissile for example:

- U235
- U238
- ... and so on

However, it is very difficult for me to construct this list. I am not sure how the different available sources denotes if it has this property or not. My best attempt is looking at the [nuclear data service API](https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/api_v0_guide.html#apiset). This API can list the decay products of an isotope. I think that is just spontaneous fission and not the neutron induced fission.

I would love your input on this.

Comment: For the ENDF database, looking on MT18 (neutron induced reactions, neutron fission cross section) would be one way. I've never done anything fancy with ENDF, so don't know how to ask it for MT18 on all isotopes. If data for MT18 does not exist then no cross section is known.

Comment: As an experiment I used the 'Extended retrieval' option in ENDF, put * for the Target, and 18 under MT # and hit return. It started coming back with a very long list...